# How to run Grails in a subdirectory?

Tags: grails

Is it possible to configure Grails to run within a subdirectory?  By default in development it runs in:

```
http://localhost:8080/appname/$controller/$action
```

I would like to configure it to run in:

```
http://localhost:8080/appname/subdirectory/$controller/$action
```

Comment: What subdirectory are you talking about? Maybe you mean url?

Comment: maybe?  I think my examples express what I'm trying to do; if you can suggest better wording that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In Config.groovy, you could add this to get the effect of it running in a subdirectory:

```
grails.app.context = '/subdirectory'
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is only about "subdirectory" in URL, just improve your URLMappings:

```
 "/subdirectory/$controller/$action?/$id?" {
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom.  Will this also serve resources at the subdirectory?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but you can write new rules for resources in UM too. Or you move the resources in the project structure to a "subdirectory" ;-) Dirty, but quick solution ;-)